# Alternative definition of Borel set

Tags: real-analysis

Borel set is defined by the smallest sigma-algebra containing all of the open sets. Can I change the definition to say the smallest sigma-algebra containing all of the **closed** sets?

Comment: Yes, since sigma algebras are closed under complements.

Comment: Elaborating on @DonThousand: a $\sigma$-algebra contains an open set $U$ if and only if it contains the complementary closed set $C$. So a $\sigma$-algebra contains all closed $C$ if and only if it contains all open $U$.